# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{a^k}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

Is there a closed form for $y=\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{a^k}$ Where $a$ is constant?

$y=x+x^{a}+x^{a^2}+x^{a^3}+...+x^{a^n}$

Note that $k$ is a power to $a$ not $x$.

It is simple to find a closed form for  $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k}$

which is $\frac {1-x^n}{1-x}$

but I tried to find a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{a^k}$ without any useful results.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404510/finding-the-sum-xx2x4x8x16-cdots might be of use

Comment: I dont think that exist a closed form for this iterated exponential function.

Comment: Generally, if there is simple form for the integral $\int_a^bf(t)dt$, there is likely no simple form for the summation $\sum_{k=a}^bf(k)$

Comment: @SimpleArt Why would a simple form for an integral imply no simple form for a summation? Is there some sort of justification for this claim?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Er, I meant the opposite, that if there is no simple integral, most likely no simple summation.