# Is there a known function defined by the sum of $x^{2^n}$?

Tags: special-functions, entire-functions

Is $$\phi(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}$$ a known special function ?

Comment: It is an example of a [lacunary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).

Comment: @JairTaylor: yes, but does it have a name and known properties ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything else other than that reference.

Comment: To get a feeling of the behaviour for $x$ close to 1 we replace the sum by an integral giving $\phi(x)=-\frac{\text{Ei}(\log (x))}{\log (2)}$, the asymptotic for $x\to 1$ f which is $\frac{-\log (1-x)-\gamma }{\log (2)} + O(1-x)$

Comment: It is interesting to consider the integral of the function. It obviously exists, and it has a closed expression: $\int_0^1 \phi(x) \,dx = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^n+1}=-1+\frac{1}{\log (2)}\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{i \pi }{\log (2)}\right) \simeq 1.2645 $

Comment: Linking to [:\[|||||\]:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404510).

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer but just a note on $x\to 1$ (following [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3253522) and [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3276218) closely).

Basically, $\phi(x)=-\log_2(1-x)+\mathcal{O}(1)$ with the "$\mathcal{O}(1)$" oscillating:
$$\psi(x)=\phi(x)+\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\ln 2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^n}{n!(2^n-1)}$$
satisfies $\psi(x)=\psi(x^2)$. The "Mellin transform approach" gives, in our case,
$$\psi\big(e^{-2^{-x}}\big)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\gamma}{\ln 2}+\frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}}\Gamma\Big(\frac{2n\pi i}{\ln 2}\Big)e^{2nx\pi i}.$$

Answer (score 2):

There are a few papers by Ahmed Sebbar where he expresses this function in terms of more well known modular forms. (though the expressions are fairly ungainly). There is a relationship with paperfolding and with automatic sequences

[On Two Lacunary Series and Modular Curves](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266992835_On_Two_Lacunary_Series_and_Modular_Curves)

[Paperfolding and modular functions](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/bessatsu/open/B52/pdf/B52_006.pdf)

This paper came out a few days ago:

[Automatic sequences defined by Theta functions and some infinite products](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.07572) by Shuo Li

The series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2^{n}}}$ is in some contexts known as *The Kempner number*, and it is known to be transcendental:

In [The Many Faces of the Kempner Number](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1685), Boris Adamczewski relates a few proofs of its transcendentality.