# Compute infinite sum - function series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wish to find an explicit expression for the following function serie:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 2^{id} \exp(-|x|^2 2^i),
$$
where $d$ is a small integer ($d=1,2,3$). It is clear that the series converges pointwise in $ \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and it converges uniformly in $ \mathbb{R}\setminus B_r(0)$ for any positive $r$, from the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) and the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

I would like to have the explicit result of the serie (as a function of $x$).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You must have meant uniform convergence out of a neighborhood of $x=0$ ('cause the series diverges there). As the sum is $(-1)^d f^{(d)}(x^2)$ where $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp(-2^n x)$, it goes [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293507). Nothing to expect (for a closed form).

Comment: You are right about the convergence domain. I edited the question.