# The sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to calculate the following sum:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{n}}$.

I know that numerically the sum is about 0.154.

Is there anyway to expand this analytically?

**Edit:

Following the comments, is there a rather "tight" analytic bound?
the obvious (not so tight) bound I can think of is the geometric sum:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{n}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2n}$

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Most probably not, though interestingly enough, $\approx \frac{\tan(57°)}{10}$ to 8 digits.

Comment: Such sums can usually only be calculated numerically, this is a very fast converging sum.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293507) (an alternative expression in my answer, and useful information in the other one), but, basically, the answer is above.